# PyAudio output a signal processed from data provided by a custom source

Tags: streaming, real-time, pyaudio

I am using a custom signal acquisition system which provides continuous data.
I have problems with streaming the data processed in real time using pyaudio.
The code looks like this :

```
import pyaudio as pya
import numpy as np
import threading
import MyAcq

fs = 50000  
NbEch = 5000
CHUNK = 1000
NbCHUNK = NbEch/CHUNK

def processing(Acq, strm):    
    while MyAcq.AcqActiv:    
    data = Acq.get_data(NbEch)      
    Sig = MyAcq.MyProcess(data).astype('float32')
    for i in range(NbCHUNK) :
        Buffer = Sig[i*CHUNK + np.arange(CHUNK)]
        strm.write(Buffer)            

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Acq = MyAcq.MyAcqSystem()
    Acq.start()
    pa = pya.PyAudio()
    stream = pa.open(format = pya.paFloat32,
                     channels = 1,
                     rate = fs,
                     frames_per_buffer = CHUNK,
                     input = False,
                     output = True)

    t = threading.Thread(target = processing, args =(Acq, stream))
    t.start()

    MyAcq.close()
    stream.stop_stream()    
    stream.close()  
    pa.terminate()
```

Though the input data stream is continuous, the signal output is chopped and distorted.
I did not figure out how to use the callback mode.
Using a queue to share the processed signal was no more successful.

Any clue ?